# Linked List that appends, prepends, delete and show contents -- Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I've just started to learn about linked lists and I am attempting to implement my understanding of it. However, it does not work and program runs without errors.

The program should be able to append, insert at the beginning, delete a node that contains a specific value and print out the contents. The program runs but does not show anything

```
public class LinkedListLogic {
    
    private class Node {
        Node next;
        int data;

        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    Node head;

    public void addToLastElement(int data) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(data);
            return;
        }

        Node current = head;
        while (current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    public void insertAtBeginning(int data) {
        Node newHead = new Node(data);
        newHead.next = head;
        head = newHead;
    }

    public void deleteAtSpecificValue(int data) {
        if (head == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (head.data == data) {
            head = head.next;
        }
        Node current = head;
        while (current.next.data != data) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = current.next.next; 
        return;                           
    }

    public void printAll() {
        for (Node current = head; current.next != null; current = current.next) {
            System.out.println(current.data);
        }
        return;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedListLogic a = new LinkedListLogic();
        a.addToLastElement(2);
        a.addToLastElement(4);
        a.printAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with a debugger?

Comment: One observation is that you don't add to the list in `addToLastElement` once `head` is non-null.

Comment: Another is that the loop in `printAll` misses off the last element of the list.

Comment: I have actually not used a debugger before. Have to watch a video on that. You are absolutely right about the addToLastElement and the printAll 
--AndyTurner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Andy Turner for pointing out the errors

```
public class LinkedListLogic {


    private class Node {
        Node next;
        int data;

        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    Node head;

    public void addToLastElement(int data) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(data);
            return;
        }

        Node current = head;
        while (current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = new Node(data);
    }

    public void insertAtBeginning(int data) {
        Node newHead = new Node(data);
        newHead.next = head;
        head = newHead;
    }

    public void deleteAtSpecificValue(int data) {
        if (head == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (head.data == data) {
            head = head.next;
        }
        Node current = head;
        while (current.next.data != data) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = current.next.next;
        return;
    }

    public void printAll() {
        Node current;
        for (current = head; current.next != null; current = current.next) {
            System.out.println(current.data);
        }
        System.out.println(current.data);
        return;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedListLogic a = new LinkedListLogic();
        a.addToLastElement(2);
        a.addToLastElement(4);
        a.insertAtBeginning(5);
        a.deleteAtSpecificValue(2);
        a.addToLastElement(9);
        a.addToLastElement(9);
        a.addToLastElement(9);
        a.addToLastElement(9);
        a.deleteAtSpecificValue(9);
        a.printAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LinkedListLogic  {

    private class Node {
        Node next;
        int data;

        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    Node head;

    public void addToLastElement(int data) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(data);
            return;
        }
        Node current = head;
        while (current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = new Node(data);
    }

    public void insertAtBeginning(int data) {
        Node newHead = new Node(data);
        newHead.next = head;
        head = newHead;
    }

    public void deleteAtSpecificValue(int data) {
        if (head == null) {
            return;
        }
      
        Node current = head;
        Node previous = null;
        while ( current != null && current.data != data) {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        if(current != null && current.data == data) {
            previous.next = current.next;
        }
        return;                           
    }

    public void printAll() {
        for (Node current = head; current != null; current = current.next) {
            System.out.print(current.data+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        return;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedListLogic  a = new LinkedListLogic ();
        a.addToLastElement(2);
        a.addToLastElement(4);
        a.addToLastElement(6);
        a.addToLastElement(9);
        a.printAll();
        a.insertAtBeginning(1);
        a.printAll();
        a.deleteAtSpecificValue(6);
        a.printAll();
        a.deleteAtSpecificValue(9);
        a.printAll();
    }
    
}
```